# Rails: Redirect to show only after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm following [Ryan Bates' guide on search functionality](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form). I've left out the implementation of the search algorithm right now, only returning So far it's doing what it should, the only problem is that now when I visit /posts, I get automatically redirected to /posts/1.

In my Posts controller:

```
  def show
  end

  def index
      @post = Post.search params[:search]
      puts ("----------------" + @post.to_s + "-----------")
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
      end
  end
```

In my index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In my Posts.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  #insert search method here
  return Post.find_by_id(1)
end
```

How can I get this so that I can visit /posts and search in my form without being automatically redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way from your implementation would be to check for params[:search].  This would be nil if you just went to /posts

```
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @post if !params[:search].nil? }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you flush out your Posts.search to do something real, that won't be the case. Instead, you'll get `@posts = []` or `@posts = nil` sometimes (depending on what you're after), and that will be its own problem. In the long run I think you'll have to have branch logic similar to

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { @post.present? ? redirect_to(@post) : render(:index) }
end
```

Also, not sure how Ryan Bates does it exactly, but I always find value in having an [ActiveModel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)-based search model. If it stays simple don't worry about it, but it's nice to have that in your bag of tricks if search starts to turn into its own beast, ex. special validations, multiple-model searching, etc.

Comment: I think this solution ends up being the same as Andrew's, because by default Rails renders index, although I'll try this out and see if I get different results. I'll check out what you said about ActiveModel though. +1